# Extract chapter from pdf (input are the two headlines before and after the chapter)

Tags: pdf, text, report, extract, finance

Hey I have to automatically extract a specific chapter from financial reports (IPO prospectus) in more than a thousand pdf files. I tried very hard by now but did not succeed. I used python until now.

The headlines of the chapters are always centered and bold. But the title can be written in upper or lowercases and different font sizes and font types. The chapter is always more than 200 words long.

Comment: The LEADTOOLS Toolkit has classes for loading and parsing text from PDF. Regular expressions (RegEx) can be used directly to isolate specific words. An example of this can be found [here](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12547-). Additionally, the [Document Analyzer](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/analyzer) class can be configured to apply multiple rules for a given text. So, a similar approach can be used to find the first input title and split off the needed text sequentially until the next title word. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)